# sql query for getting data from three tables with common columns in any two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

help me out
i have three tables like this

```
        tblccestudentgrades
        ID Studentcode assessareamappingcode
        1   Max            40002
        2   Roy            50002

        tblcceassessareamapping 
        ID assessmentareacode  assessareamappingcode
        1  10002                 40002
        2  10003                 50002

       tblcceassessmentarea
       ID  assessmentareaname  assessmentareacode
       1    Maths               10002
       2    English             10003
```

iam getting data from other tables too.but my main table here is the first one i.e tblccestudentgrades
.Now what query should i use so thati get assessmentareaname based on the assessmentareamapping code from tblccestudentgrades..
Can any one tell me how to do this

Comment: I don't like these column names! Remember the Pen Island debacle. And why prefic tables with tbl? It's in a database. Unless otherwise informed, I think we can assume it's a table!

Comment: check link for solution http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/10cac/9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  tblccestudentgrades.Studentcode , tblcceassessmentarea.assessmentareaname  
FROM dbo.tblccestudentgrades
INNER JOIN dbo.tblcceassessareamapping 
ON  tblccestudentgrades.assessareamappingcode = tblcceassessareamapping.assessareamappingcode
INNER JOIN tblcceassessmentarea
ON tblcceassessareamapping.assessmentareacode = tblcceassessmentarea.assessmentareacode
```

Comment: irfan i need to join tblccestudentgrades with many tables and not tblcceassessmentarea.pls help

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables:

```
select * 
from tblccestudentgrades s
join tblcceassessareamapping m on(m.assessareamappingcode = s.assessareamappingcode)
join tblcceassessmentarea w on(w.assessmentareacode = m.assessmentareacode)
```

Comment: it is not showing any result

Comment: check the field names in my joins, it could be that I joined using wrong fields (sorry but your field / table names suck). Anyway, the idea how to do it should be clear. If the field names are correct and resultset is empty then you don't have matching records in all the tables.

Comment: i have 20 records in tblassessmentarea and i have 20 records in tblcceassessareamapping but i have only 5 records in tblccestudentgrades .so i should get those 5 records right.but it is showing nothing

Comment: i used this query.but this resulted in getting so manny records repeated again and again    select a.assessmentareaname from tblccestudentgrades1 s
join tblcceassessmentarea1 a
 where a.assessmentareacode in (SELECT assessmentareacode FROM tblcceassessmentareamapping1 t
join tblccestudentgrades1 c on t.assessmentareamappingcode=c.assessmentareamappingcode) and sub.type<>'Languages';